# Submodule commits are missing locally

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to switch to a branch with a submodule in it. But I'm getting:

```
fatal: failed to unpack tree object shaxxx
error: submodule xxx could not be updated
```

So I ran:

```
git switch --recursive-submodules=false xxx
```

I then cd into the submodule and run

```
git pull origin xxx
```

but when I do `git log` I don't see the latest commits on the submodule branch. It's like git is checking locally and not trying to get the latest commits. So origin/xxx is an old commit in the log.

I cloned out the repository into a new folder and was able to switch to this branch without issue so the problem relates to the state of this local repository. `git log` in the submodule for the newly cloned out repo shows the latest commits on origin.

I also tried:

```
git submodule update --force --recursive --init --remote
```

but its listing the older sha commit for my submodule. Again doesn't seem like it's going to GitHub to get the change.

`git log origin/xxx` in the submodule is not showing the latest commits in origin either.

How might I go about fixing my repo?

Comment: Is the output of `git remote -v` inside the submodule what you expect?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, and its the same in the new folder I cloned out where I can switch without issue.

Comment: My bet would be that the commit you need in the submodule was on a branch that got rebased, which would make that commit no longer accessible. Did you rebase-merge a PR in the submodule, for example? That would have invalidated the submodule commit in the parent repo.

Comment: If the submodule PR was merged on GitHub, the reference might still exist on GitHub. A `git clone --mirror` of the submodule will include it if it's there.

Comment: @Baz Have you figured out the problem, with either solution proposed?

Answer (score 1):

##### Option 1: with luck, the sha is still on the remote

This can happen if the submodule sha was on a branch that got rebased. It might still be on the remote server, but it won't get fetched by default if it's not reachable from any branch.

However, you can fetch it explicitly by sha1. Let's call the sha the parent wants `badsha`.

```
cd path/to/submodule
git fetch origin badsha
git checkout badsha
git checkout -b recovery-branch
```

If `badsha` still exists on the remote, `git fetch origin badsha` should have fetched it, then enabling you to check it out and create a branch to be able to manipulate it again.

##### Option 2: find someone who still has the sha

If that doesn't work, then `badsha` no longer exists on the remote. My next strategy would be to find someone who might still have it in a sandbox.

The person who committed this update to the submodules is likely to still have `badsha` in their sandbox. Or maybe a collaborator or colleague has a sandbox that still has that reference in it if they fetched/pulled/cloned while it was reachable from a branch.

The key is, if anyone still has `badsha` in a sandbox, they can create a branch from it and push it:

```
git checkout badsha
git checkout -b recovery-branch
```

##### Option 3: give up on that sha

If you cannot recover `badsha` from the remote or a colleague/collaborator, you can recover the repo by giving up on that submodule commit.

Just checkout `origin/main` in the submodule, and commit the changes in the parent.

While that's not ideal, it would make the repo usable again and then you could try to figure out what code is missing in the submodule.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by design flaw in Git (*one* of them anyway).

Recurse-on-fetch can cause a `fetch` to fail if a submodule is in a detached HEAD state. Issuing this command will work around this issue most of the time (I've had this setting in my git config for 6 years):

```bash
git config --global fetch.recurseSubmodules false
```

In your case, you can run this command to make sure you have all commits downloaded for all submodules:

```bash
git submodule foreach git fetch --all
```